# Android: My custom View isn't adding an overlay (TextView) on certain rotations

Tags: android, android-custom-view

In Android I'm trying to make a Custom View where the user can sign, like the android finger paint api demo, and it has an overlay (essentially a TextView) that goes away when touched. I need to be able to add this view programmatically.

I couldn't figure out how to make this in an xml layout, so I added the overlay view in onSizeChanged.

It works but sometimes when I rotate the device twice rapidly it doesn't display even though it should. The rest of the View works fine. My View is called PaintOverlayView.

The relevant code is

```
private TextView overlay= new TextView(getContext());

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
...
LayoutParams wrapped = new LayoutParams(w,h);
    overlay.setId(50);
    overlay.setText("Click to draw, double click to clear");
    overlay.setTextSize(20);
    overlay.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    overlay.setX(this.getX());
    overlay.setY(this.getY());
    overlay.setLayoutParams(wrapped);
    overlay.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Touch Event");
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            overlayed=false;
            //System.out.println("overlayed on tocuh overlay "+overlayed);
            return false;
        }
    });
    ViewGroup Par =(ViewGroup)this.getParent();
    Par.addView(overlay);
    System.out.println("overlayed on Size Changed "+overlayed);
    System.out.println("visibility "+overlay.getVisibility());
    /*if (!overlayed)
        overlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        overlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    */
}
```

I rotate it and sometimes the overlay doesn't show up even though ovarlyed is true and the visibility is still set to 0 (visible).

Edit: In case it helps I'm trying to add the PaintOverlayView to a RelativeLayout

Comment: Maybe instead of relying on the system to call onSizeChanged(), you can make it a method you call in onCreateView() of your Activity?

Comment: Problem with that is that I have unknown number of these views and so I'd need an unknown number of booleans to check if the overlap is still there on size change for each view.